# Configuring TheWeekinChess downloads with Megadatabase 2014

Tags: chessbase

This quite a technical question, anybody who knows about the program Chessbase (12) and how it works please feel free to answer.

Recently I downloaded many PGN files from the website The Week in Chess,

I copied all of the games (over 100,000) into my current **unedited** version of **Chessbase Megadatabase 2014**, the games were installed **successfully**.

The problem is that when I do the *'Opening Report'* and the player *'Dossier'*, I find that my TheWeekinChess download games are **ignored**, I know this because all of the TheWeekinChess downloads are games from 2014 and none of these are shown in the Opening Reports (main lines) and player Dossiers (top players).

For example, I input the moves `1.e4 c5` (Sicilian), click *Opening Report* and it works but the latest games are all played in 2013 even though there are games from the year 2014 in the database.

I search for a player in the Player Encyclopedia, for example: Magnus Carlsen, I click dossier and it works perfectly fine; but then again the games go no further than 2013.

Could anyone show me a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Out of curiosity why did you download in pgn format when Mark Crowther also has the downloads in cbv (Chessbase) format?

Comment: Pgn is Easier for me, I also do not see the difference between the two other than the fact that with .cbv you can see the players/tournaments tabs which I do not use as I put it into a compilative database anyways.

Comment: PGN files are text files. To see the details of what they contain all you have to do is open them with any simple text editor. ChessBase files are binary. Unless you know the proprietary format you do not know the details of what they contain. They may very well contain data over and above that which is displayed by default in ChessBase. For me it would be a no-brainer to use the default format for a particular program rather than a degraded text semi-equivalent. I have to admit to being puzzled as to what way pgn files are easier. With both formats you just import.

Comment: Pgn files are easier as when a database is opened it creates multiple files (not copies) which is problematic for organization other than that no difference besides the already mentioned, and this binary and text-file (degraded) hullabaloo I do not really see the significance sorry and I am happy using pgn :)

Answer (score 1):

The Mega Database 2014 is in chessbase format and contains not only the games but several pre-requisite to all options proposed by Chessbase 12.
So by using pgn files, you will find the games in your database but they are not optimize for the others options.